# Very simple AngularJS widget using custom Directive

Tags: html, angularjs, widget

I'm working to learn AngularJS right now and it has been a bit of a bumpy process. Today I started trying to make a VERY simple test widget using AngularJS but I can't seem to get it working. I'm pretty sure it is a quick fix but I'm not experienced enough to recognize what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help with this specific widget or general AngularJS pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Simple Directive File:

```
//simpleDirective.js
var messagesApp = angular.module("messagesApp", []);



messagesApp.directive('message', function(){
    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.template = "{{successMessage}}";

    directive.scope = false;

    return directive;

});
```

Simple Sample Page File:

```
<html ng-app="messagesApp">

<body ng-controller="simpleController">


<message>This text should be replaced.</message>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="simpleDirective.js"><script>

<script> 
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", []);
function SimpleController($scope){

    if(1 == 1)
    $scope.successMessage = "Item saved successfully";

    else
        $scope.successMessage = "NONE";
}


testApp.controller('simpleController', SimpleController);
</script>


</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of problems here :

1) Your controller is defined in a different module to the ng-app module you pointed to in your html. correct it to point to the correct module.

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
```

2) You need to inject your directive module into your controller module so that it is available.

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", ["messagesApp"]);
```

Refer to this plunk for the complete solution : http://plnkr.co/edit/zld5lG4mLK3sSP2P0DX0?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer!!